# When do we normalize a wave equation? In what kind of problems/exercises? Why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, normalization

I'studying quantum mechanics, and i haven't understand very well, when should we normalize the wave equation?
And why must we normalize it?

Comment: Physically meaningful states must be normalizable because they represent probability distributions. I think that there is no such thing as normalizing a wave equation. The states have to be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

We always normalize the wave equation. Any state must be normalized before deductions related to an arbitrary physical observable is made because the only realistically achievable states are those which satisfy the Born's interpretation.

The reason for normalization is statistical. We have attached a physical significance to the wave functions by the square of its absolute value. For example in the position representation of a wave state of a single particle, let the wavefunction be given as $\psi(x,t)$. Then the probability of finding the particle between $x$ and $x+dx$ is given as $\vert \psi(x,t)\vert^2dx$. Clearly, since the particle must be found somewhere we need to have$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vert \psi(x,t)\vert^2dx=1$$ Of course there are states which cannot be normalized this way, but they do not correspond to a particle state.
As for when to normalize and which questions demand normalization, you should remember that as long as you know that the wavefunction corresponds to a particle/system of particles, you need to normalize it.